# Download a file from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, extjs

I'm trying to download a file from the response of an AJAX call, using ExtJS. From the server side I send the byte stream of the file using Java and Spring. I think this works just fine because when I use Postman, I can download my file with no problem.

When I try to download it from the browser (Chrome), although the download works, the file seems to be corrupted. First I choose what type of file I want (CSV, PDF or Excel), the back-end converts my file to it and then sends it to the front-end. The CSV works, but PDF shows nothing and Excel says the file is corrupted. From what I tried, I think that the problem might be the encoding, the sent byte stream is not the same as the one downloaded by Chrome.

This is the ExtJS code:

```
function runScript(id, text) {
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/report/execute',
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    jsonData: { id: id,
                type: text },
    cors: true,
    waitMsg: 'Sending data ...',
    success: function (response) {
        var disposition = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        var filename = disposition.slice(disposition.indexOf("=")+1,disposition.length);
        var blob = new Blob([response.responseText]);
        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        }
        else {
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            if (filename) {
                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                // safari doesn't support this yet
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        }
            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
    },
    failure: function () {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', 'Download failed!');
    }
});

Ext.getCmp('sqlview').getStore().load();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the MIME type of the data contained in the Blob.

```
var contentType = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
var blob = new Blob([response.responseText], {
  type: contentType
});
```

Make sure your backend is giving correct value for the 'Content-Type'.
Expected values for the file types are:

- CSV: `text/csv`
- PDF: `application/pdf`
- Excel: `application/vnd.ms-excel`